# how can I iterate through this json file?

Tags: json, reactjs

I want to do my cv in react.
I have a json file that contains all my experience, education and more however I come across a problem when I output the data

```
{

    "experience":[
        {
            "Title":"Somewhere",
            "Date":"2015 - 2015",
            "Description": 
            [
                "Participate in the full development lifecycle, following a SCRUM methodology applied to core product",
                "Participate in the full development lifecycle, following a SCRUM methodology applied to core product",
                "Participate in the full development lifecycle, following a SCRUM methodology applied to core product"
            ]

        },
        {
            "Title":"Somewhere",
            "Date":"2015 - 2015",
            "Description": 
            [
                "Participate in the full development lifecycle, following a SCRUM methodology applied to core product",
                "Participate in the full development lifecycle, following a SCRUM methodology applied to core product",
                "Participate in the full development lifecycle, following a SCRUM methodology applied to core product"
            ]

        }

    ]
}
```

I am calling it in experience.js

```
const Experience = (props) => (
    <div className="container">
        <p className="subtitle">WORK EXPERIENCE</p>
        <hr className="subtitles"/>

        <ul className="left-box"> 
    {props.data.map((info,i) =>
            <li key={i} className="top">
                <div className="year">
                        <h4>{info.Date}</h4>
                        <span> {info.Title}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="box-content" >
                    <h4 className="sameHeightTitle">Front End Developer</h4>
                    <ul className="left-box-content">
                        <li className="sec-layer">
                        {info.Description}
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </li>
    )}
    </ul>
    </div>
    );
```

the problem is instead of having the description in bullet form I have it all on the same bullet. Basically every string that starts with Participate in my json file should be next to a new bullet.The following is screenshot of the output:

[image]

EDIT: Answer

```
const Experience = (props) => (
    <div className="container">
        <p className="subtitle">WORK EXPERIENCE</p>
        <hr className="subtitles"/>

        <ul className="left-box"> 
    {props.data.map((info,i) =>
            <li key={i} className="top">
                <div className="year">
                        <span className="sub-sub-title"> {info.Title}</span>
                        <h4>{info.Date}</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="box-content" >
                    <h4 className="sameHeightTitle">Front End Developer</h4>
                    <ul className="left-box-content">
                    {info.Description.map((newDesc, o)=>
                        <li>
                        {newDesc}
                        </li>
                        )}

                    </ul>

                </div>
            </li>
    )}
    </ul>
    </div>
    );
```

Comment: You have to map across the entries in `Description` to generate your list entries

Comment: @SkinnyJ I tried to do it, but i failed miserably...
So would I need to do something like:

`{info.Description.map((newInfo, i) =>

<li>
{newIfno}
</li>
)}`

Comment: That does not provide enough information to know how to help you

Comment: @SkinnyJ I just updated my reply

Comment: got it, I tried it so many times but it wouldnt work, maybe I was messing up some syntax somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Description` is an array. You need to iterate over it. What js library are you using? You'll need to find out how you iterate over a list in that language.

This isn't the syntax for the foreach loop, but you'll get the idea.

```
foreach(var description in info.Description){
                    <li className="sec-layer">
                    {description}
                    </li>
}
```

Comment: i dont think you can do that in react inside of a functional stateless component. I tried it and it is saying description undefined oh sry just read the part where it says this isnt the syntax...

Comment: I know that I need to iterate through the Array, I am having trouble figuring how to iterate